# Is it possible to use \includeonly, but display the full document?

Tags: include

Say I have

```
\documentclass{article}
\includeonly{part2}
\begin{document}
\include{part1}
\include{part2}
\include{part3}
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to compile only part2 by using the \includeonly command while displaying in the viewer the whole document so that I can scroll up and down to part1 and part3 to view what I have written there while writing new text to part2?

If it's important, I'm using TexStudio.

Comment: No, that is not possible

Answer (score 1):

As @Herbert already said: this is not really possible with your `\includeonly` approach. As soon as you compile only part 2, the pdf will only contain this part.

Another approach would could be to use `subfiles`. This allows you to compile your main file and the individual parts separately. This means that during compilation of part 2 you can open the pdf of the main file and browse the other sections.

Small caveat: The changes you make in part 2 will only be included in the pdf f the main file if you recompile it.